# Haskell : how to count words

Tags: haskell

I am new Haskell learner, and trying to do count words, but there are errors.   how can i change to code and show the result like this

```
countWords ["friend","she","she"] 
 >[("friend",1),("she",2)
```

here is code

```
Prelude Data.List> countWords xs = map(\w -> (head w, length w)) 
 $group $ sort $ words xs
Prelude Data.List> countWords ["hello", "hello", "world"]
```

:101:13: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the expression: "hello"
      In the first argument of ‘countWords’, namely
        ‘["hello", "hello", "world"]’
      In the expression: countWords ["hello", "hello", "world"]

:101:22: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the expression: "hello"
      In the first argument of ‘countWords’, namely
        ‘["hello", "hello", "world"]’
      In the expression: countWords ["hello", "hello", "world"]

:101:31: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the expression: "world"
      In the first argument of ‘countWords’, namely
        ‘["hello", "hello", "world"]’
      In the expression: countWords ["hello", "hello", "world"]

Thank you

Comment: `words` expects a single string, not a list of strings. Are you sure you need `words` at all? The input seems to be already split into words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @chi said - `words :: String -> [String]`  so either change the input type for your function to a single string of words separated by whitespace, or omit the `words` part, i.e.

```
countWords :: [String] -> [(String,Int)]
countWords xs = map (\w -> (head w, length w)) $ group $ sort xs
```

an example usage for this:

```
Prelude Data.List> countWords ["hello", "hello", "world"]
> [("hello",2),("world",1)]
```

or

```
countWords :: String -> [(String,Int)]
countWords xs = map (\w -> (head w, length w)) $ group $ sort $ words xs
```

an example usage:

```
Prelude Data.List> countWords "hello hello world"
> [("hello",2),("world",1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's break this down to a simpler example:

```
Prelude> xs = ["hello", "hello", "world"]
Prelude> words xs

<interactive>:2:7: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: [[Char]]
    • In the first argument of ‘words’, namely ‘xs’
      In the expression: words xs
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = words xs
```

As you can see, we get a type error at the application of `words`. Further investigation shows us the problem:

```
Prelude> :t words
words :: String -> [String]
Prelude> :t xs
xs :: [[Char]]
```

Here we see the types for `words` and `xs`. First, `words` expects a `String` as its argument. However, `xs` type is `[[Char]]`. Since `[Char]` is the same as `String`, `xs` type can also be given as `[String]`.

Now we see the problem. You are passing a `[String]` (a list of `String`s) to a function which expects a single `String`.